# alternative method of creating string from list

Tags: c#

Have such function, which creates string from List of ids
I try to run it in 50 threads, and after 30 seconds it hangs app

```
public string genText(List<string> list)
{
    string text = @"{""text"":""";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < list.Count - 1)
            text += "!" + " ";
        else
            text += "!" + @""", ";
    }

    text += @"""start"":[";
    for (int i = 0, lim = -2; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        lim += 2;
        if (i < list.Count - 1)
            text += @"""" + lim + @""",";
        else
            text += @"""" + lim + @"""], ";
    }

    text += @"""end"":[";

    for (int i = 1, lim = -1; i < list.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        lim += 2;
        if (i < list.Count)
            text += @"""" + lim + @""",";
        else
            text += @"""" + lim + @"""], ";
    }

    text += @"""type"":[";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < list.Count - 1)
            text += @"""USER"",";
        else
            text += @"""USER""], ";
    }

    text += @"""objectId"":[";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < list.Count - 1)
            text += @"""" + list[i] + @""",";
        else
            text += @"""" + list[i] + @"""]}";
    }

    return text;
}
```

What i­­­­­­­­­­­­­­s the best (alternative) way of writing such functio­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­n?

Expected result: `{"text":"! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! !", "start":["0","2","4","6","8","10","12","14","16","18","20","22","24","26","28"], "end":["1","3","5","7","9","11","13","15","17","19","21","23","25","27","29"], "type":["USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER","USER"], "objectId":["524231066205","363249609235","509321690322","551832845250","273337925148","553378679618","552270073142","256641407","545454406232","548096729194","555315805314","553271555117","573655339037","518779453704","486606264340"]}`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Use a JSON library like JSON.NET

Comment: I also recommend using json.net if you are generating json.  But if you are working with a lot of strings in the future, use a `StringBuilder` instead of just string concatenation.

Comment: 50 threads???...your serious?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating strings it is much more efficient to use the StringBuilder class.

```
public string genText(List<string> list)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    text.Append(@"{""text"":""");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < list.Count - 1)
            text.Append("!" + " ");

    ...

    return text.ToString();
}
```

but as other have mentioned in the comments, use a Json library if you want to create Json data.